# Github GraphQL API v4 Query on CommitAuthor

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

I am trying to run the following query on Githubs GraphQL api:

```
{
  user(login: "davekaj") {
    id
    repositories(first: 10, orderBy: {field: NAME, direction: ASC}) {
      nodes {
        ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first: 15, author: "WHAT DO I PUT HERE") {
                totalCount
                nodes {
                  additions
                  author {
                    name
                    user {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                  committedDate
                  deletions
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It wants me to filter on a `CommitAuthor` for `history(author: )`. I tried passing my username, or my unique user ID, but it doesn't work. I am essentially passing it a string, but it wants the type `CommitAuthor`. How do I pass a `CommitAuthor` value?

It isn't clear to me, and I searched through the docs and the schema and I couldn't find anything.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so the answer is actually very simple once I looked at the graphql documentation (rather than just the github documentation). `CommitAuthor` is an input type, which is described here https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/.

The result is you pass an object of `CommitAuthor`. In this case I just have to pass the id, which looks like this: `author: {id: "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDE3Mzgy"}`

See the completed code below.

```
{
  user(login: "davekaj") {
    id
    repositories(first: 10, orderBy: {field: NAME, direction: ASC}) {
      nodes {
        ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first: 15, author: {id: "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDE3Mzgy"}) {
                totalCount
                nodes {
                  additions
                  author {
                    name
                    user {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                  committedDate
                  deletions
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```